# How to disable eslint's rule for logging using 'node-file-logger' package in node.js?

Tags: node.js, logging, eslint

In my code I am using '**node-file-logger**' for logging purposes and also using 'eslint'.
**Eslint** is showing warning for using log.Debug with fewer arguments than expected.

I want to know that how can I disable this Eslint rule without modifying my existing **log.Debug** statements?

node-file-logger logging interface for debug:

```
    Debug: function(errorMessage, serviceName, methodName, errorObj, cb) {
        logger(options, 'Debug', errorMessage, serviceName, methodName, errorObj, cb);
    },
```

My Code:

```
log.Debug("Some debug log message")
```

Eslint:

```
Expected 5 arguments, but got 2.ts(2554)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the eslint rule for any line using this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line name-of-your-rule

log.Debug("Some debug log message")
```